# Struts2 - Allow user to login to approve item

Tags: authentication, struts2

I need to allow a user to log in to my struts2 web app and approve an image.
They can only see their images pending approval and should not have access to the rest of the site.

This is to replace an old process of emailing the user images pending approval.

Please! Does anyone have any ideas about how this could be done??

Comment: What have you come up with so far?

Answer (score 0):

I'd put all the jsp's under WEB-INF.  Then make sure all the image access actions are contained under an interceptor which checks if the user is logged in (*SecurityInterceptor*) otherwise it would redirect them to the login screen.  You'll need to create an action to log the user in and set a session variable which would satisfy this. Then I'd store the images in a DB because I like putting everything in a DB the row would probably contain: UseID (the user who owns rights to access this image, description, date posted, and the image).

You could just buy Struts2 in Action.  The book teaches by creating a simple demo application step by step.  The demo application is an image gallery which address all the above points and more.

Answer (score 0):

But you have said is more related to authentication and authorization and does not a problem specific to Struts2.
Just google for authorization and authentication and you will get a lot of example.